# iOS 8 iCloud Drive and previous core data DB in iCloud

Tags: core-data, ios8, icloud

My question is: Do data previously stored in iCloud using Core Data + iCloud are connected with the iCloud Drive migration? So if my users choose to move to iCloud Drive after iOS8 do their Core Data DB will be moved to iCloud Drive? or this migration is only related with Documents?

Answer (score 1):

if your users mov to iCloud drive, they can continue using their apps that use core data + iCloud. but for proper functioning they should upgrade their iCloud to iCloud drive on all devices they use.